# Strange exception in SBT test

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I am facing an issue with SBT (version 0.13.9). One of my ScalaTest tests fails not deterministic with `EOFException`.

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-155" Exception in thread "Thread-159" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at sbt.React.react(ForkTests.scala:114)
at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$mainTestTask$1$Acceptor$2$.run(ForkTests.scala:74)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestRunner$Skeleton$1$React.react(Framework.scala:953)
at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestRunner$Skeleton$1.run(Framework.scala:942)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

sbt.ForkMain 59974 failed with exit code 134
```

I don't see any JVM logs or thread dumps.

Answer (score 10):

Almost certainly this is related to the Java classpath being too long when invoking `sbt.ForkMain` in certain linux distros. To avoid this I added

```
javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Xms1G","-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled","-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC")
```

to the `build.sbt` file.  I reckon `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` is where the magic happens.

Comment: I have the same issue and this has fixed it. If you're able to provide any clarification on exactly why this would help though that'd be amazing! I don't understand why having class unloading enabled would change behaviour.

Comment: Sorry @Timmeh I tried to find out exactly why is working but couldn't find anything really useful.

Answer (score 3):

SBT single thread or multi threaded tests forks the JVM and if the host name is not resolved it just fails with this error message. If you look at the logs in the tests, you might see

> Uncaught exception when running tests: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

So the easy way to resolve this is to add your hostname to the /etc/hosts and map it to localhost something like this

::1             localhost       blahblah

This should resolve the issue.